# CONCAT() between different alphabet echoes out '&' ampersand

Tags: mysql, concat

I want to concatenate different alphabet strings and get a weird latin encoding with ampersands after the sixth greek character (I want to concatenate greek and english alphabet strings).

Lets say I have :

COL 1   COL 2
John    Johnson

and instead of John Johnson i get John Johnso&adasdasa

any help ?

Comment: Much more details? Table structures, method of viewing the result, and so on...

Comment: I guess that you can find the sixth character, so after that you can just concatenate the symbol, or use one of the following function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html . Anyway, how do you get this Greek character and how do you intent to use it? If you give more details even a solution might appear here, give us the use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COLLATE :

`concat(COL1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci,COL2 COLLATE latin1_general_ci)`

`latin1_general_ci` is an example, try to figure it out what collation do u have.

But i think this should work, you could try `latin1_general_cs` too.

Comment: `COLLATE` is how to compare the value.